# react-map-gl using multiple sources makes one of them invisible

Tags: mapbox, react-map-gl

I've specified two `<Source>` elements under `ReactMapGL` trying to load two different `FeatureCollection`s with different coloring. It doesn't work when both `Source`s are present as it hides the first (id: `maps-with-yield`) and shows the latter (id: `maps-without-yield`).

The following warning is also printed for the first `Source`.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fill-color' of undefined
```

Are we not allowed to use multiple sources or am I doing something wrong here?

```
<MapGL
  {...viewport}
  mapboxApiAccessToken={accessToken}
  onViewportChange={viewport => setViewport(viewport)}
  onHover={onHover}
  onClick={onClick}
  onLoad={onLoad}
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  scrollZoom={false}
  dragRotate={false}
  touchRotate={false}
  keyboard={false}
>
  {map && map.features.length > 0 ? (
    <Source id="maps-with-yield" type="geojson" data={map}>
      <Layer
        id="data"
        type="fill"
        paint={{
          'fill-color': {
            property: 'yield',
            stops: [
              [minYield, worstYieldColor],
              [maxYield, bestYieldColor]
            ]
          },
          'fill-outline-color': '#fff'
        }}
      />
    </Source>
  ) : null}
  {mapWithoutYield && mapWithoutYield.features.length > 0 ? (
    <Source id="maps-without-yield" type="geojson" data={mapWithoutYield}>
      <Layer
        id="data"
        type="fill"
        paint={{
          'fill-color': '#66AEEC',
          'fill-outline-color': '#fff'
        }}
      />
    </Source>
  ) : null}
</MapGL>
```

Note: property `yield` is always available as I've printed both `map` and `mapWithoutYield` data sets and checked.

Comment: Try to use same source and layer and modify features according type of data.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience, **react-map-gl does allow multiple sources**. The problem here is likely to be the IDs given to different layers.

Even from different sources of data, you should still assign unique `id` to each individual layer for Mapbox to recognize them as well as make it easier for future development (for instance, setting active layers).

Same `id` (`"data"`) will lead to your second layer overwritting the first one and that's the reason why the `fill-color` property cannot be read for your `maps-with-yield` layer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the issue was that I was using the same `id` for the two different layers, as described by Ethan. I had followed the [GeoJSON code example](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/tree/7.0-release/examples/geojson), so I had this:

```js
    const boundaryStyle = {
        'id': 'data',
        'type': 'line',
        'paint': {
            'line-color': "#f00"
        }
    }
    const protectedSegmentStyle = {
        'id': 'data',
        'type': 'line',
        'paint': {
            'line-color': "#00f",
            'line-width': 2
        }
    }
```

And then for the layers, I had the following:

```js
          <Source type="geojson" data={protectedSegments}>
            <Layer {...protectedSegmentStyle} />
          </Source>
          <Source type="geojson" data={boundaries}>
            <Layer {...boundaryStyle} />
          </Source>
```

Of course, this was providing the same `id` of `data` for both layers, since the style objects were getting [spread](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/operator-lookup?match=restspread) into the tag as arguments. So as soon as I provided unique `id`s in my style dictionaries, both layers appeared.